# How to map a vec of values in tuple to a vec of refs in tuple?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to implement a function of `fn foo (v: Vec<(String, String)>) -> Vec<(&String, &String)>`?

I tried it as `v.into_iter().map(|(a, b)| (&a, &b)).collect()`.

Comment: that an xy problem https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that exact function signature would be possible, because you're not allowed to return references to data owned by the current function, which it would be because the vec was passed by value. But you could do it if you can pass the vec by reference to the conversion function instead ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3577c312ba7086c74f4bd49bdc323a3)):

```rust
fn vec_to_vec_ref (strings: &Vec<(String, String)>) -> Vec<(&String, &String)> {
    let mut vec_ref = Vec::new();
    for (a, b) in strings {
        vec_ref.push((a, b));
    }
    vec_ref
}

fn vec_ref (strings: Vec<(&String, &String)>) {
    println!("Success! {:?}", strings);
}

fn main() {
    let strings = vec![(String::from("Foo"), String::from("Bar"))];
    vec_ref(vec_to_vec_ref(&strings));
}
```

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, simply replace `into_iter` for `iter`:

```rust
let strings = vec![(String::from("Foo"), String::from("Bar"))]
let strings_refs: Vec<(&String, &String)> = strings.iter().map(|(a, b)| (a, b)).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abe4a8c4f270b0f739cb799326ad0d47)

With `into_iter` you are taking the values owned (`(String, String)`) meanwhile with `iter` you get a reference to the tuple (`&(String, String)`), by repacking the inner String references in the `map` section we get the final target result `(&String, &String)`.

We can expand that to functions, for example, taking an iterator already, or an slice over the data:

```rust
fn foo<'a> (v: impl Iterator<Item=&'a(String, String)>) -> Vec<(&'a String, &'a String)> {
    v.map(|(a, b)| (a, b)).collect()
}

fn foo_slice<'a> (v: &'a [(String, String)]) -> Vec<(&'a String, &'a String)> {
    v.iter().map(|(a, b)| (a, b)).collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb0d01e44a0cbc90dbe3e45c31b84d0f)

Comment: This only works in your playground because you use static values. It won't work in the general case (and in particular if you try to encapsulate the code in a function).

Comment: @Jmb if you are referring to the fact that with consuming a  `Vec<T>` is impossible to safely return a `Vec<&T>` from a function, yes indeed.

Comment: Thanks. It does not work in my case. But glad to know the ownership difference between `iter` and `into_iter`.